# How can I pop the previous view from the stack in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, stack

I have an app with 3 view controllers. I use push segues to push from A->B->C. After B pushes to C how can I remove B from the stack leaving just two views, C on top of A?

Comment: Take a look at `-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]`

Comment: And for what it's worth, while `setViewControllers...` will allow you to do what you want, you should probably put some thought into whether it's really the best interface design possible.

Comment: @David I'm having a problem with my turn based game leaving unnecessary view controllers on the stack while moving in and out of game center. I was under the impression that I needed to remove them to preserve memory as well as keep my views clean. I have used this code as you suggested:  NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
    [viewControllers removeLastObject];
    [viewControllers addObject:self];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES]; ...it works but is it acceptable?

Comment: I agree with David's implication that this probably is far from the best decision from a UX standpoint.  Give it some thought on how better to navigate from point A to point B perhaps, or perhaps find a way to use less memory for your view controllers?  You can put a LOT of view controllers on the navigation stack without running into memory issue... so your performance issues aren't simply a result of an extra VC or two on the nav stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has an array of view controllers which it maintains to manage the navigation stack.

The objects at the smaller indexes are lower in the stack then objects at the higher index.  The object at the highest index is at the top of the navigation stack, with the object at index 0 being the root view controller.

You can access this array view the `viewControllers` property.  For any `UIViewController` in a navigation controller, simply:

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

You can use this to grab the array in its current state, manipulate it however you want, and then reset it.

For example:

```
NSArray *oldNavigationStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

NSArray *newNavigationStack = @[[oldNavigationStack firstObject],
                                [oldNavigationStack lastObject]];

self.navigationController.viewControllers = newNavigationStack;
```